# GoogleError: Error opening file: gs://mybucket/a.subpath/output.json

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to do OCR on a PDF and am having difficulty getting it to work. I am getting this error:

```
    GoogleError: Error opening file: gs://mybucket/a.subpath/output.json
        at Operation._unpackResponse (/Users/my/project/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/longRunningCalls/longrunning.js:148:31)
        at /Users/my/project/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/longRunningCalls/longrunning.js:134:18 {
      code: 7
    }
```

When running this Node.js script:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision').v1

const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

parse('a.something')

function parse(name) {
  var bucketName = `mybucket`

  const features = [{type: 'DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION'}]

  let requests = []
  let i = 0

  while (i < 10) {
    requests.push({
      inputConfig: {
        mimeType: 'application/pdf',
        gcsSource: {
          uri: `gs://${bucketName}/${name}.${i + 1}.pdf`
        },
      },
      features: features,
      outputConfig: {
        gcsDestination: {
          uri: `gs://${bucketName}/${name}.${i + 1}/`,
        },
      },
    })

    i++
  }

  const request = {
    requests
  }

  client.asyncBatchAnnotateFiles(request).then(x => {
    let [operation] = x
    operation.promise().then(y => {
      let [filesResponse] = y
      const destinationUri =
        filesResponse.responses[0].outputConfig.gcsDestination.uri
      console.log('Json saved to: ' + destinationUri)
      process.exit()
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
      process.exit()
    })
  })
}
```

This is straight from the docs pretty much.

At first I just went into the console and uploaded the PDFs into Cloud Storage manually. I was logged in as `foo@gmail.com`. A few days before I created a JSON API key to `export` in the shell, for project `bar` (which I created when logged in as `foo@gmail.com`). I then got this error above. So what I tried doing is adding a new member to the project, who had my email `foo@gmail.com`. Then I gave them the roles *I think* equivalent to `roles/storage.legacyObjectOwner`, which were these:

[image]

Then, when I run the Node.js script, I get this error still. I don't know what's going on or how to fix it, any ideas?

Comment: Your code is using Application Default Credentials (ADC). What did you do to set up the credentials (service account JSON file)? I recommend actually specifying the service account JSON file when creating the client if running at your desktop. If running in Google Cloud, what are you running on?

Comment: I am running this from my Mac locally. I went to the Cloud browser console > API & Services > Credentials > Create Credentials > Service account key > New Service Account > JSON > Create. Then in the terminal I `export`ed the downloaded JSON file. This is logged in as `foo@gmail.com` under project `bar`.

Comment: And then you did what with the JSON file to configure your program to use the service account? This article that I wrote might help you understand how to setup ADC: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-application-default-credentials/

Comment: I did `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/some/place/bar-e618a51a1bf9.json`, where the JSON file was literally at `/Users/some/place/bar-e618a51a1bf9.json`. I am just hacking something together right now so I'm not concerned if this is the most robust way to manage the credentials, but it should work like this.

Comment: Does `cat $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` display the contents of your service account file? I strongly recommend specifying the service account when you create the Vision Client.

Comment: It is something like this: `{ "type": "service_account", "project_id": "bar", ...privatekeystuff..., "client_email": "whatinamedmycredentials@foo.iam.gserviceaccount.com" }`

Comment: I don't recognize that `client_email`, should that be my actual email `foo@gmail.com`? What does it mean?

Comment: Service accounts do NOT have the format `foo@gmail.com`. They have their own email address. You need to assign roles to the service account email address in the Google Cloud IAM console.

Comment: The problem is most likely you have assigned the correct roles to the wrong IAM member ID (email address).

Comment: The picture above is for `Roles for "bar" project`

Comment: THAT WORKED YOU SAVED THE DAY :) :) :) Thank you!!!